# Angular-UI and Bootstrap-UI together

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm very new to AngularJS. Please let me know how can I use BOTH Angular-UI and Bootstrap-UI in the same page (application).

**OR**

How can I use just the Angular-UI (which I supposed to be the parent of bootstrap-UI) but having Bootstrap-UI functionality?

**UPDATE ( Solution )**

I'm not allowed to answer my question so, I put the solution here...

`angular.module('app', ['ui','ui.bootstrap']);`

Answer (score 1):

UI Bootstrap (AngularJS) and Twitter Bootstrap (Components and JavaScript) can be used together on a single project, but the behavior may be slightly different for some elements. This is not recommended, since it will be redundant.

You can also look into making of AngularStrap.
AngularStrap is a set of native directives that enables seamless integration of Bootstrap 3.0 into your AngularJS 1.2 application.

For more information, please refer:-
http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/

Answer (score 0):

This is bootstrap definition in angular controller:

```
var myModule = angular.module('App', ['ui.bootstrap']);

 myModule.controller('Monitor', function($scope) {

 }

 myModule.$inject = ['$scope'];
```

All bootstrap sources you add to header (wrapper) like in jQuery.

Comment: It works like this:

angular.module('app', ['ui','ui.bootstrap']);

...just as simple ;)

Thank you anyway Steff